# Hosting a WCF service that accepts a MTOM request, but gives a non MTOM response

Tags: .net, wcf, mtom

I am creating a WCF webservice that has to accept an MTOM encoded request, but give a standard text response. Is there a way to change the configuration to force this behavior?

Comment: Could you define the term *standard text response*? Is it plain text or do you want to support some protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the type of message encoding for incoming and outgoing messages. However you can define a custom message encoder for a composite encoder.

Here you can find enough information about [implementing a composite encoder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/11/09/wcf-extensibility-message-encoders.aspx). The example in this blog post creates a custom message encoder that reads a message encoded with MTOM and writes the response message encoded in xml.